# Combining REST API with RPC

Tags: rest, rpc

I'm working on a CRM-like application that manages a list of companies via REST api:

```
GET     /api/companies
POST    /api/companies
PUT     /api/company/1
DELETE  /api/company/1
```

Now a new requirement has been declared: the API must provide a way to copy some properties from one company to another. There are several property sets which can be copied independently - for example, a list of managers and payment information.

What is the best way of adding such a method to the existing API?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please clarify what does your PUT and POST operations do?

If I had to design such API, I would have done it like the following

- GET     /api/companies -> Get the list of companies
- POST /api/companies -> Add a new company to the list (i.e, it will
  add a    new one to the /api/companies list and create a resource for
  the new    company as /api/companies/1)
- PUT    /api/companies/1 -> modify the company information
- DELETE /api/companies/1 -> delete a company

In this case, if I want to copy some information from company 1 to company 2

- GET /api/companies/1
- GET /api/companies/2

copy the necessary information from the company 1 state to the to company 2 state and

- PUT /api/companies/2

Is this what you need or you need to copy those information in a single HTTP operation?

Comment: Oops, I mixed up the PUT and POST urls - it's fixed now.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It, however, seems redundant to send the whole data object to client and then back to server. Isn't there any convention of naming actions that do not correspond to CRUD operations?